# Change Laravel Unisharp file manager save location

Tags: php, laravel

I am just trying to use this [package](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager) to use as a file manager, however the default saves it directly to the public directory, and not under storage, would there be a way to change the location to storage? I am using laravel 5.6 and the latest package.

Comment: Read the doc: https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/config#working-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish config file and implement configuration :

https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/blob/master/docs/config.md#user-content-working-director.